# JavaScript Replace Text with Image

Tags: javascript, node.js, replace, str-replace, replaceall

I'm still newbie, I want to replace all 'Snowman' text in the string chain for images of snowman.
Is there any easy possibility to do this in only JS?

Ok I forgot this is important too. It gets string chains actually from my Twitch channel chat to my local server using websocket node.js. When someone comment on the Twitch channel it goes into my local server in the string chain format. What I want to do is to replace or change the comment like Snowman to actual Image of Snowman.

I have very low experience with the DOM and jQuery but if this would help I can try.

Code:
    Analyzing the twitch chat:

```
wsTwitch.onmessage = function(event) {
let eventData = JSON.parse(event.data);


Replacing text with image:

eventData2 = eventData.text.replace(/Snowman/gi, "img src='snowman.png'");
```

Comment: Hi @TechNeck, Can you give us a example string ?

Comment: I updated the question maybe this will help to resolve :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try like below

`eventData2 = eventData.text.replace(/Snowman/gi, "<img src='path/snowman.png' />");`

This will might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```js
var txtArr = eventData.text.split(' ');

for(var i = 0; i < txtArr.length; i++){
  if(txtArr[i] === "Snowman")
    txtArr[i] = `<img src="url">`;
}

var newTxt = txtArr.join(' ');
document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = newTxt; //replace with existing element
```